# How to concatenate Attribute value in innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
var counter=0;
for(..){

Element.innerHTML = '<div id="myId">....</div>';

counter++;
}
```

and i want to do the following, generating the ID dynamically:

```
for(..){
var counter=0;
...
Element.innerHTML = '<div id="myId'+counter+'">....</div>';
...
counter++;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Appears one issue is `counter` is reset to `0` at each iteration of `for` loop?

Comment: sorry the counter is already outside of the loop,the code is very long, and tried to reduce. im looping through JSON objects and transforming them to HTML divs dynamically, i thought i had a mistake, but it was already right. I just forgot to make the same changes in other divs using the ID (bootstrap Collapse, popover...). And i need for my template each loop a new ID, to produce a different div

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
var counter = 0;
```

outside of the for loop, because you reset it on every loop.

```
var counter = 0;
for(...){
    //...
    Element.innerHTML = '<div id="myId'+counter+'">....</div>';
    //...
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a separate counter if you are already using a for loop.
Don't use capitalized `Element` as a variable name. It is already a [DOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and I can't think of a reason you should be overriding that. Even if it causes no current issues in your code, it's bad practice.

```
var element = document.body // or grab any dom node
var someAmount = 10 // or any amount

// assuming you are looking to add additional divs with each iteration
// which is what I assume you mean by 'concatenate'
for (var i = 0; i < someAmount; i++) {
  element.innerHTML += '<div id="myId'+i+'">....</div>'
}
```